# How to enable 16 bit color in ili9486?

Tags: c, display, lcd

Wanna use 16 bit color, changed register `3A` to `0x55` and when I’m trying to fill out my screen with red color `0xf800`, nothing happens. When I use 18 bit color `0x3A = 0x66` red color is correct

**UPD:** Here is my piece of code that I used for 18 bit and how I rewrite it to use with 16 bit

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t cmd;
    uint8_t data[16];
    uint8_t databytes;
} lcd_init_cmd_t;

// 18 bit color
DRAM_ATTR static const lcd_init_cmd_t ili_init_cmds_18b[]={
    /* SW reset */
    {0x01, {0}, 0},
    /* Sleep out, also SW reset */
    {0x11, {0}, 0},
    {0xc0, {0x0D, 0x0D}, 2},
    /* 18 bit - 0x66, 16 bit 0x55 */
    {0x3A, {0x66}, 1},
    /* Power Control 3 (For Normal Mode) */ 
    {0xC2, {0x44}, 1},
    /* VCOM Control */
    {0xC5, {0,0,0,0}, 4},
    /* Positive gamma correction */
    {0xE0, {0x0F, 0x1F, 0x1C, 0x0C, 0x0F, 0x08, 0x48, 0X98, 0x37, 0x0A, 0x13, 0x04, 0x11, 0x0D, 0x00}, 15},
    /* Negative gamma correction */
    {0xE1, {0x0F, 0x32, 0x2E, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x05, 0x47, 0x75, 0x37, 0x06, 0x10, 0x03, 0x24, 0x20, 0x00}, 15},
    /* Display Inversion OFF */
    {0x20, {0}, 0},
    /* Memory access contorl, MX=MY=0, MV=1, ML=0, BGR=1, MH=0 */
    {0x36, {0x28}, 1},
    /* Display on */
    {0x29, {0}, 0},
};
// 16 bit color
DRAM_ATTR static const lcd_init_cmd_t ili_init_cmds_16b[] = {
    {0x01, {0}, 0},
    {0x28, {0}, 0},
    {0x11, {0}, 0},
    {0xC0, {0x0D, 0x0D}, 2},
    {0xc1, {0x43, 0x00}, 2},
    {0xc2, {0x00}, 1},
    {0xC5, {0x00, 0x48}, 2},
    {0xB6, {0x00, 0x01, 0x3B}, 3},
    {0xE0, {0x0F, 0x24, 0x1C, 0x0A, 0x0F, 0x08, 0x43, 0x88, 0x32, 0x0F, 0x10, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x00}, 15},
    {0xE1, {0x0F, 0x38, 0x30, 0x09, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x4E, 0x77, 0x3C, 0x07, 0x10, 0x05, 0x23, 0x1B, 0x00}, 15},
    {0x20, {0x00}, 1},
    {0x36, {0xE8}, 1},
    {0x3A, {0x55}, 1},
    {0x2A, {0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xDF}, 4},
    {0x2B, {0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x3F}, 4},
    {0x29, {0x00}, 0}
}; // 16-bit color

void lcd_init(){
ili_init_cmds = ili_init_cmds_18b; // <- pseudocode
//Send all the commands
    uint8_t len = sizeof(ili_init_cmds)/sizeof(ili_init_cmds[0]);
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<len; i++){
        lcd_cmd(spi, ili_init_cmds[i].cmd);
        lcd_data(spi, ili_init_cmds[i].data, ili_init_cmds[i].databytes & 0x1F);
        if (ili_init_cmds[i].cmd == 0x01 || ili_init_cmds[i].cmd == 0x11 || ili_init_cmds[i].cmd == 0x28 || ili_init_cmds[i].cmd == 0x29){
            vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_RATE_MS);        
        }
    }

}

void fill_screen(){
uint16_t color = 0xf800;
uint8_t GRAM_BUFF[1440] = {0}; // width 480 pixels * 3 bytes of color
uint16_t i;
// for 18 bit
for(i=0; i<1440; i+=3){
   GRAM_BUFF[i] = RGB_R(color);
   GRAM_BUFF[i+1] = RGB_G(color);
   GRAM_BUFF[i+2] = RGB_B(color);
}
// for 16 bit
for (i=0; i< 1440; i+=2){
   GRAM_BUFF[i] = (uint8_t)(color >> 8);
   GRAM_BUFF[i+1] = (uint8_t)(color);
}

for (i=0; i<HEIGHT; i+=3){ // HEIGHT = 320pixels
   send_lines(spi, i, GRAM_BUFF);
}
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @PMF I don’t use any special libraries. I use esp32 and its SDK esp-idf and want to understand how to manage this display by changing colors, changing simultaneous frame rate, etc. moreover most libraries I used use 18 bit color

Comment: Then it may be useful if you share some code (e.g. what registers you write and how exactly you set the frame buffer).

Comment: @PMF Yes, sure. I updated my post by adding piece of code I use

Comment: You are missing the `send_lines` implementation. Also, I'm not sure about the memory layout in 16 bit mode. The Chapter about the frame buffer organisation in the spec sheet is very confusing. I did get this to work, however with an Ili9342.

Comment: @PMF there is no special implementation for `send_lines`, I took it from [esp-idf examples](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/peripherals/spi_master/lcd/main/spi_master_example_main.c) and edited some values. Datasheet says that 16 bit is simply RGR565, so `F800h` is already converted to RGB565 red color